# How to get "dl" value?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Below is my code
How to get dl of id value?

{[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "abbr": null,
    "pid": 4,
    "dn": null,
    "dt": null,
    "nm": "WC1457Y-KL",
    "pnm": null,
    "ic": 2,
    "dl": [
      {
        "id": "916072284",
        "io": "",
        "nflt": null,
        "pid": 3,
        "st": null,
        "ic": 0,
        "tc": 0,
        "cn": "CH1,CH2,CH3",
        "cc": 3,
        "tn": "",
        "sim": null,
        "md": 353
      }
    ]

}

]
}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do? Regex ? Is this a string or an object? Please give more details about your problem and show your code try!

Comment: String value,No problem I got the result.